# How to set nice float value using Apache POI?

Tags: java, floating-point, apache-poi, cell, xls

I'm trying to set a cell value to a nice `float` value. I want to set cell value to `5.2`, but I get `5.1999998093` instead. What would be a solution for this?

```
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet();
CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("0.0"));

int i = 0;
worksheet.createRow(i + 1);
worksheet.getRow(i + 1).createCell(0).setCellStyle(style);
worksheet.getRow(i + 1).getCell(0).setCellValue(new BigDecimal("5.2").floatValue());
```

Comment: why would it require to create BigDecimal and then getting float value?

Comment: actually to make code easier to read, I replaced `listData.get(i).getLength()` with `5.2`

Comment: The replacement of 5.2 with something close to 5.1999998093 is required by the use of `floatValue()` in the code. That forces use of a value that can be represented as a float.

Comment: Instead of use .floatValue() you can use .doubleValue(), infact setCellValue method takes a double as parameter, if you pass a fload you force an implicit conversion, and during this conversion you get the change of value, due to internal representation of float and double

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You guys didn't understand what was my problem well. A solution was to change data format:

```
DataFormat format = workbook.createDataFormat();
style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("#.#"));
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to voluntarily limit the precision of your desired value by using a `float`.  There's also no reason for using `BigDecimal` if all you need is a `float`.

Because `5.2` can't be represented exactly as a binary number, the closest `float` to the true "5.2" value is `5.19999980926513`.  If you need the cell to be numeric, you can use a `double` which has more precision.  Besides, the [`setCellValue` method is overloaded to take a `double`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue%28double%29), not a `float`.

Your line in question:

```
worksheet.getRow(i + 1).getCell(0).setCellValue(new BigDecimal("5.2").floatValue());
```

... can be replaced with something simpler:

```
worksheet.getRow(i + 1).getCell(0).setCellValue(5.2);
```

The `double` value `5.2` is much closer to the "true" 5.2 value than the `float` value `5.2f` that you get with the float literal `5.2f` or from `new BigDecimal("5.2").floatValue()`.  You will see `5.2` in Excel, in the actual cell and in the bar that shows the actual cell value.  You don't even need to set the data format.

If you are required to use `BigDecimal`, maybe because you get a `BigDecimal` from somewhere else, and you simplified your code example here with `new BigDecimal("5.2")`, then at least call `doubleValue()`, and you can still set the cell value with a `double`:

```
worksheet.getRow(i + 1).getCell(0).setCellValue(new BigDecimal("5.2").doubleValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `BigDecimal.setScale`
simple example

```
 BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.valueOf(5.165);
    BigDecimal roundOff = a.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
    System.out.println(roundOff);
```

**output**

```
5.2
```

This is another way

```
double d = 5.165;
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.0");
System.out.println(f.format(d));
```

**output**
5.2

Comment: BigDecimal returns "5.2" value, so it's not it's fault, something may be wrong in HSSFDataFormat.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `toPlainString()` instead of `floatValue()`

```
new BigDecimal("5.2").toPlainString()
```

Edit:

```
new BigDecimal("5.2").setScale(2).floatValue()
```

Comment: but I need to set it as number, not as string in xls file.

Comment: You can set scale by using `setScale`. see my edited answer. I pass `2` as argument by assuming, you can define your own.

Comment: BigDecimal returns "5.2" value, it's not it's fault, something may be wrong in data format.

Comment: Good approach but .setScale(2) doesn't make it scaled to 2 in excel.