# Not able to apply specific cell data format using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to write data into Excel. I am trying to write a big decimal number to an Excel cell and I am using the following methods to so:

#1:

```
CellStyle style= wb.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(df.getFormat("000.0000000"));
```

#2:

```
CellStyle style= wb.createCellStyle();
HSSFCreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
style.setDataFormat(
    createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("000.0000000"));
```

Below is the required format:

```
0.0000000   ---> 000.0000000
1.0000000   ---> 001.0000000
10.0000000  ---> 010.0000000
101.0068721 ---> 101.0068721
111.0034360 ---> 111.0034360
010.0034526 ---> 010.0034526
100.1452672 ---> 100.1452672
```

But i am ending up with the output below using above data format:

```
0.0000000   ---> 000.0000000
1.0000000   ---> 000.0000000
10.0000000  ---> 000.0000000
101.0068721 ---> 000.0068721
111.0034360 ---> 000.0000000
010.0034526 ---> 000.0034526
100.1452672 ---> 000.1452672
```

What's the correct data format?

Comment: Are you certain you're really writing the correct values into the cells?

Comment: See if this question helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332944/how-to-set-nice-float-value-using-apache-poi

Comment: Can you share the piece of code where you actually set the value?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a '**#**' instead of '**0**' before the decimal point. So, your data format should be '**##0.0000000**'.